# Loop wont close for unknown reason when printing Mandelbrot Set

Tags: c

I am trying to print the mandelbrot set in spaces and asterisks', but for some reason this code produces an infinite set of spaces.

The loop definitely closes and I reset all my variables, but it just not  working. I am so stuck and some help would be amazing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>


#define MAX_HOROZ 2
#define MAX_VERT 2
#define MAX_ITERATION 255
#define PIXEL_SIZE 0.0078125 //4/512

  int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

   double row = -2; // y
   double col = -2; // x
   double xtemp;
   double realValue;
   double imagValue;
   int iteration = 0;

   while (row < MAX_VERT) {
     while (col < MAX_HOROZ) {
       imagValue = 0;
       realValue = 0;
       iteration = 0;
       while ((iteration < MAX_ITERATION)&&
             ((realValue*realValue +imagValue*imagValue)< 4)) {
         xtemp = realValue*realValue +imagValue*imagValue +col;
         imagValue = 2*realValue*imagValue +row;
         realValue = xtemp;
         iteration++;
       }
       if (iteration == MAX_ITERATIONS) {
         printf ("*");
       } 
       else {
         printf(" ");
       }
       col += PIXEL_SIZE;
     }    
     row = 0;
     printf("\n");
     row += PIXEL_SIZE;

   } 


   return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
  }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Most of the problems will get solved by that simple approach.

Comment: Verify `row = 0;` — shouldn;t it be `col = 0;`...?

Comment: Every point within the mandelbrot set is contained within the points [-2,2]  so if i want to print it between these values shouldnt my start points be -2, -2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
row = 0;
...
row += PIXEL_SIZE;
```

at the bottom. So, When checking `while (row < MAX_VERT)`, the variable `row` is either `-2` or `-2 + PIXEL_SIZE`.

Perhaps you meant `col = 0;` instead of `row = 0;`?

Comment: Yes that was a mistake of mine thank you. The loop is ending now, however it is still not printing the correct shape at all. It is printing a large set of empty lines, then an incrementing number of asteriks' over the course of multiple lines, before decreasing back down to empty new lines